# Aptana 3 doesn't execute the ruby code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aptana

I have installed Aptana to create a Rails App. But my problem is that Aptana 3 doesn't execute the ruby code.
When I run my app in Firefox, I get the code without execution.
When I run my app in the browser of Aptana, it execute HTML, CSS, but not Rails.

For exemple, with CSS, When I use rails :

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

the CSS is not execute. But when I use HTML and CSS (like with PHP) :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="./css/design.css" />
```

the CSS is execute, even in the browser of Aptana.

My Os is Windows 10. I ma not sure that is a good choice to create ruby app, because there are a lot of bugs with ruby on Windows. The problem is maybe here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started working on Aptana with Ruby on Windows. I dropped both, (Aptana and Windows) for development purposes: Ruby is **extremely slow** on Windows, due to some bugs related to File System management. Aptana was too buggy, couldn't deal with a language as dynamic as Ruby. Aptana performs an "approximation" of what Ruby code should perform (otherwise it would have been too slow), so it won't work fine with it, I'm sorry.

I've heard good things about RubyMine, although it's a paid IDE. That being said, I came from Visual Studio, so I was really used to having **a lot** of fancy stuff: autocompletion, very integrated language with the editor itself and such. Although, in the end, I moved to a simple editor: now I use Sublime Text or Atom, they are simple text editors, no special support for Ruby, but they work very well, you'll discover that you don't need all that fancy stuff, Ruby it's very human readable, so you'll remember most stuff through memory, for everything else, you can search it.

I know probably it's not what you want to hear, but I had to drop Aptana for one of those reasons, in addition to a few bugs.

Actually, Ruby was more performant using a virtual machine inside Windows (with Kubuntu as OS) rathern than using it on Windows itself

Comment: Thank you verry much for your answer !

In fact, I have a virtual machine (VirtualBox) and I have installed Linux Fedora, but I have problems to install solftware...

I used too Sublime Text. In fact, Ruby is very easy to read.

I need a solution to test my web app before send it on the Internet. Do you have a solution on Windows ? I can installed Kubuntu or Debian in a virtual machine.

Thank you !

Comment: In a virtual machine, go with something like Lubuntu (or xubuntu), which are very light while preserving a *buntu environment. Use sublime text inside and you should be good to go to write/test your application. Use git though and push to a private repository, so you won't loose data in case your VM crashes badly.

Comment: Thank you veru much for your advices. I have downloaded Kubuntu. Now, I will indstalled Kubuntu on my computer, with a private repository in my SSD. Thank you !!